# Sort days of the week depending on time slots

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array of data in PHP.

```
$office_hours = [ 
    "monday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm",
    "tuesday" => "true",
    "wednesday" => "10:00 am - 12:30 pm",
    "thursday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm",
    "friday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm",
    "saturday" => "10:00 am - 4:00 pm",
    "sunday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm"
];
```

I would like to sort the array to have the days that are similar to make string `Mon,Thu,Fri, Sun 9-5, Wed 10-12:20, Sat 10-4 while Tue is available on appointments.`

```
$office_hours = [ 
        "monday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm",
        "tuesday" => "true",
        "wednesday" => "10:00 am - 12:30 pm",
        "thursday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm",
        "friday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm",
        "saturday" => "10:00 am - 4:00 pm",
        "sunday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm"
    ];

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $office_hours );
    echo '</pre>';

    $appointment_days = [];

    foreach ( $office_hours as $day => $hours ):
        if( is_string( $hours ) ) {
            echo '<span>' . ucfirst($day) . ' ' . $hours . '</span><br>';
        }
        if( true ===  $hours ) {
            array_push( $appointment_days, $day );
        }
    endforeach;
    
    if ( ! empty($appointment_days) ) {
        echo '<span>' . 'while ' . ucwords( implode( ", ", $appointment_days ) ) . ' are ' . 'available on appointments' . '</span>';
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why you added 9-5 in your string for sunday but not for Mon,Thu,Fri ?

Comment: whats with the `tuesday = true`? is that a mistake?

Comment: FYI: What you want, is not really “sorting”.

Comment: I’d start by collecting the days in an array, using the hours as key: https://3v4l.org/nP5Df The rest, from there, is basically text manipulation.

Comment: @Crimin4L It is not. I am using that to make an appointment. It is a different data set.

Comment: @CBroe That makes sense. Please add the anser here so I can tick it.

Comment: @Crimin4L, mind restoring your answer? (Unless you are not satisfied with it for some reason.) That said basically the same thing as I suggested in a comment only, so I don’t see why yours should not be the answer, if it helps OP.

Comment: @CBroe Ahh okay I restored it; I wasn't sure if i was close or really off with the answer as this question got me a bit confused haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the array into a new array, putting the values of the old as the keys of the new, so any values that are identical will be put together. Then you can print them how you want

```
<?php
    
    $office_hours = [ 
        "monday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm",
        "tuesday" => "true",
        "wednesday" => "10:00 am - 12:30 pm",
        "thursday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm",
        "friday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm",
        "saturday" => "10:00 am - 4:00 pm",
        "sunday" => "9:00 am - 5:00 pm"
    ];
    $narr = [];
    foreach($office_hours as $key => $val){
        $narr[$val][] = $key;
    }
    print_r($narr);
```

Then to get your expected result, you can iterate through the data like so:

```
    foreach($narr as $time => $arr){
        $str = "";
        foreach($arr as $days){
            if(strstr($days, "nesday")){
                $day = strtr($days, array_combine(["nesday"], [""]));
                $str .= ucfirst($day).", ";
            }elseif(strstr($days, "urday")){
                $day = strtr($days, array_combine(["urday"], [""]));
                $str .= ucfirst($day).", ";
            }elseif(strstr($days, "day")){
                $day = strtr($days, array_combine(["day"], [""]));
                $str .= ucfirst($day).", ";
            }
        }
        print_r(substr($str, 0, (strlen($str) - 2)).": $time");
        print_r(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);
    }
```

Print_r Output:

```
Array
(
    [9:00 am - 5:00 pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => monday
            [1] => thursday
            [2] => friday
            [3] => sunday
        )

    [true] => Array
        (
            [0] => tuesday
        )

    [10:00 am - 12:30 pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => wednesday
        )

    [10:00 am - 4:00 pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => saturday
        )

)
```

Expected Results Output:

```
Mon, Thurs, Fri, Sun: 9:00 am - 5:00 pm

Tues: true

Wed: 10:00 am - 12:30 pm

Sat: 10:00 am - 4:00 pm
```

Live Demo:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d67d709d2799c5932403447750b5f06c00c13c9

Answer (score 0):

Create another array `$office_hours_flipped` and loops over `$office_hours` and flipped `day` by `hours` and store `hours` as key, With this way, the same `hours` will accumulate theirs days.

```php
$office_hours_flipped = [];
foreach ($office_hours as $day => $hours ){
    $office_hours_flipped[$hours][] = $day;
}
```

```php
print_r($office_hours_flipped);
```

*Print:*

```
Array
(
    [9:00 am - 5:00 pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => monday
            [1] => thursday
            [2] => friday
            [3] => sunday
        )

    [true] => Array
        (
            [0] => tuesday
        )

    [10:00 am - 12:30 pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => wednesday
        )

    [10:00 am - 4:00 pm] => Array
        (
            [0] => saturday
        )

)
```

To generate this sentence:

> Mon,Thu,Fri, Sun 9-5, Wed 10-12:20, Sat 10-4 while Tue is available on appointments.

```php
$appointment_days = [];
foreach ($office_hours_flipped as $hours => $days) {
    if($hours == "true"){
        $appointment_days['days'] = $days;
    }else{
        [$s, $e] = explode(' - ', $hours);
        foreach ($days as $day) {
            $d[] = substr(ucfirst($day), 0, 3);
        }
        echo implode(', ', $d).' : '.substr($s, 0, 5).' - '.substr($e, 0, 5)."<br>";
        $d = [];
    }
}
echo ($appointment_days) ? "While ".join(', ', $appointment_days['days'])." is available on appointments." : '';
```

*Display:*

```
Mon, Thu, Fri, Sun : 9:00  - 5:00 
Wed : 10:00 - 12:30
Sat : 10:00 - 4:00 
While tuesday is available on appointments.
```